# How does std::map::extract() allow changing the key?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, stdmap, const-cast

I am writing a template class similar to `std::map`. Currently I'm working on implementing a function equivalent to `std::map::extract()`. This should return a node handle with its own function `node_type::key()`, that returns a non-const reference to the key. This therefore allows changing the key associated with a mapped object and thus avoids moving the mapped object.

`std::map` exposes its value as `std::pair<const Key,T>`, but somehow allows changing the `Key` object through a `node_type` object. I don't understand how STL implementations deal with this? I am lead to believe that they include const_cast conversions, but all resources I read heavily discourage the use of const_casts for fear of undefined behaviour, especially when changing the value afterwards.

[This resource](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0083r3.pdf) invokes "implementation magic".

How can I implement `std::map::extract()` without causing undefined behaviour?

### Related Questions

- [Using std::map::extract to modify key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53196275/using-stdmapextract-to-modify-key)
- [Rationale of restrictive rules for extract and re-insert with map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53209889/rationale-of-restrictive-rules-for-extract-and-re-insert-with-map)
- [Is it possible to cast a pair<Key, Value> to a pair<const Key, Value>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305793/is-it-possible-to-cast-a-pairkey-value-to-a-pairconst-key-value/64399851?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top)
- [Type punning between `pair<Key, Value>` and `pair<const Key, Value>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72670928/type-punning-between-pairkey-value-and-pairconst-key-value)

Comment: Implementations can avoid undefined behavior by simply defining it for a specific use case. That's the "implementation magic".

Comment: `std::map` probably does not handle `std::pair<const Key, T>` internally but a better suited node type (I've no proof of that , it's just my guess).

Comment: @Fareanor But that would mean that any access to the pair would require a copy of the value

Comment: @Fareanor `std::map`s iterator dereferences to `std::pair<const Key, T>`, meaning that there must be an underlying `pair` object, no?

Comment: @BoP Then my question would be, how do I do that?

Comment: @gerum You're right, it invalidates my guess. In that case, I don't know how it is done (but the given answer seems to give a good explanation).

Comment: @chiasmos "implementation magic" is created by having a talk with the guys writing the compiler. Perhaps they can add a [__builtin_x](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) function for the x you need. Or let you have a `#pragma magic make_this_work` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I implement `std::map::extract()` without causing undefined behaviour?

You can't. The standard specifies behaviour that is not implementable in portable C++.

An implementer (of C++) will be required to have implementation-defined additional guarantees, which need not be exposed to user code, to handle this requirement. This is colloquially known as "implementation magic".

What you could do is write a proposal, submit it to the committee, and get it voted into a future standard; such that there is a mechanism by which this can be accomplished. *implicit-lifetime-types* that arrived in C++20 did a similar thing to the requirements on `std::vector::data`.

Comment: Interesting. This seems to be the answer I'm looking for, thank you. Would you care to elaborate what you mean by "portable" c++ here? I guess it means that the implementation is platform-dependant, but why must that be?

Comment: @chiasmos When you start with a `std::pair<const Key, Value>`, and some valid pointers and references to those objects, turn it into a `std::pair<Key, Value>` and then back into a `std::pair<const Key, Value>`, the pointers and references still have to be valid. The rules about object lifetimes don't allow that. Whatever solution an implementer might come up with *must* be tied to the rest of the implementation